# combined nested foreach loop in mirth

Tags: javascript, mirth

Working through CCDA for labs need to loop through parent child and child segments but the variable for "Lab" is not working however "Section" and "Header" are working:

```
var file=""; var header="";  var Lab=""; var section="";


header=msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['name']['family'].toString()+"|"+ //last name msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['name']['given'].toString()+"|"+ //first name msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['administrativeGenderCode']['@code'].toString()+"|"+ //gender msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['birthTime']['@value'].toString(); //DOB msg['component']['structuredBody']['component'][8]['section']['title'].toString()
               for each (seg in msg..component)
                {    Lab = "";
                  Lab =seg['section']['title'].toString();
                  if (section == "Results")
                 {
                   for each (seg in seg..entry..organizer)
                {

                       Lab+= seg ['code']['@code'].toString()+"|"+ //LOINC code
                       seg ['code']['@displayName'].toString()+"|"+//actText
                       seg ['effectiveTime']['@value'].toString();//collection timestamp

                          }
                       }
                } for each (seg in msg..component)
                {
                  section = "";
                  section =seg['section']['title'].toString();
                  if (section == "Results")

                 {
                   for each (seg in seg..entry..organizer..component)
                {

                       file+=header+"|"+Lab+"|"+
                       seg ['observation']['code']['@code'].toString()+"|"+ //LOINC code
                       seg ['observation']['code']['@displayName'].toString()+"|"+//actText
                       seg ['observation']['effectiveTime']['@value'].toString()+"|"+//result timestamp
                       seg ['observation']['value']['@value'].toString()+"|"+//result value
                       seg ['observation']['value']['@unit'].toString()+"|"+//result unit
                       seg ['observation']['interpretationCode']['@code'].toString()+"!!!"+"\r"+"\n";//interpretationCode

                          }
                       }
                }

channelMap.put("FILE",file);
```

Answer (score 0):

'for each' is deprecated,  use 'for';

you have a syntax error on line 2 (the single line comments )
header=...

the statement should be split over several lines

```
 header=msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['name']['family'].toString()+"|"+ //last name
 msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['name']['given'].toString()+"|"+ //first name 
 msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['administrativeGenderCode']['@code'].toString()+"|"+ //gender 
 msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['birthTime']['@value'].toString(); //DOB 
 msg['component']['structuredBody']['component'][8]['section']['title'].toString();
```

dot dot syntax only works on number literals

```
556..toString()==="556"
```

replace all .. by . (a single point)

in the first loop section never changes its initial value of "";
section == "Results" evaluates always to false, its subsequent if branch never executes.

are you using an xml to json parser ?
i don't believe that hou need to call toString()
the cast is done automatically ( string + something is transformed by the interpreter into string + something.toString() )

```
var file="",
  header="",
  Lab="",
  section="";


header=msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['name']['family'].toString()+"|"+ //last name
  msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['name']['given'].toString()+"|"+ //first name 
  msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['administrativeGenderCode']['@code'].toString()+"|"+ //gender 
  msg['recordTarget']['patientRole']['patient']['birthTime']['@value'].toString(); //DOB 
  msg['component']['structuredBody']['component'][8]['section']['title'].toString();

for(seg in msg.component){
  Lab = "";
  Lab =seg['section']['title'].toString();
  if (section == "Results"){
      for(seg in seg  .entry  .organizer){

     Lab+= seg ['code']['@code'].toString()+"|"+ 
        //LOINC code
      seg ['code']['@displayName'].toString()+"|"+
        //actText
      seg ['effectiveTime']['@value'].toString();
        //collection timestamp

    }
  }
}

for(seg in msg.component){
  section = "";
  section =seg['section']['title'].toString();
  if (section == "Results"){
   for(seg in seg.entry.organizer.component){
    file+=header+"|"+Lab+"|"+
    seg ['observation']['code']['@code'].toString()+"|"+
      //LOINC code
    seg ['observation']['code']['@displayName'].toString()+"|"+
      //actText
    seg ['observation']['effectiveTime']['@value'].toString()+"|"+
      //result timestamp
    seg ['observation']['value']['@value'].toString()+"|"+
      //result value
    seg ['observation']['value']['@unit'].toString()+"|"+
      //result unit
    seg ['observation']['interpretationCode']['@code'].toString()+"!!!"+"\r"+"\n";
      //interpretationCode
    }
  }
}

channelMap.put("FILE",file);
```

Comment: Thanks - Header and Section actually work perfectly its the Lab loop that is broken - it is picking up the 'title' of 'Plan of Care' which comes after Results and that is the part I'm not understanding.  I am not using xml to json parser rather the message tree parser with in Mirth